# Heroku: What happens when my Redis connection are all used?

Tags: heroku, redis, resque, websub

I'm using Redis for Queue and a few other simple things. resque is one of them I will be using Redis for, my question is that what happens when my 10 connections all are used when using a resque ?

Will it wait until one of them finished and to go into a Que ? or it fails right away when my 10 connections are all in use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Redis is configured with a maxclients limit of 10, any new connection attempt will get the error `ERR max number of clients reached`. Resque will try to reconnect three times, and it will raise an error if it the max number of reconnection attempts is reached. You can see the code [here](https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/8f13ad5b61a2c68dcf9f92980920008184359099/lib/resque/backend.rb#L80-L103).